# How to check if your location has been confirmed in Android?

Tags: android, geolocation, location

I'm building an app that involves getting the user's current location. I already have it getting the location, but sometimes it's inaccurate.

I've noticed that when I start the app, a location services symbol appears greyed out in the notice bar. While it's greyed out my app will sometimes report that I'm where I was an hour ago, even if I'm miles away. A few moments later the symbol will be solid and then the app reports the correct location.

The phone seems to understand that it's not entirely sure for moment. Is there a way to check this programmatically?

I'm aware of how to check if location services are enabled. The problem is that my location is not updating quickly enough and I'd like to wait until the phone is absolutely sure of where I am.

My current fix is to make a fake loading screen that just forces the user to sit for a few seconds, but this seems a bit sloppy. Also, I have no guarantee that the location will have updated properly by the end of the three seconds.

I'm trying to avoid making the app run in the background and check periodically because I'm worried about draining the battery.

Comment: Can't you just check the date and time of the last known location? If you also factor in the accuracy of the last known location you should have more than enough data to judge the validity of the location data.

Comment: Thanks. This may work, but when I tried checking the time of the last known location, it sometimes never found it. I noticed that sometimes my app can't find my location, even if Google Maps can. Is there a way to find my location other than checking gps and network?